# Implement breadth-first search using Hama

Tags: breadth-first-search, bsp, hama

I've done some research, and I seem to be missing one small part.I understand how a Breadth-First Search works, but I don't understand how to partition nodes so that it can be computed parallely using hama.Is there any method to do it?